# Unable to cast object of type System.Func`2 with Int64

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, dynamic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using dynamic = System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Project.Lib.Extensions
{
    public static partial class Utils
    {
        public static List<T> SortForMe<T>(this List<T> list, string propertyName,SortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            string exp1 = string.Format("model.{0}", propertyName);
            var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "model");
            var e1 = dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p1 }, null, exp1);

            if (e1 != null)
            {
                if (sortDirection==SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    var result = list.OrderBy((Func<T, object>)e1.Compile()).ToList();
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = list.OrderByDescending((Func<T, object>)e1.Compile()).ToList();
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this code for sorting my Generic List by propertyName. When the property type is `string`, this code runs successfully, but when the type is `long` or `int`, I am getting this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Func`2[Project.Lib.Model.UserQueryCount,System.Int64]' to type
>   'System.Func`2[Project.Lib.Model.UserQueryCount,System.Object]'.

---

```
var result = list.OrderBy((Func<T, dyamic>)e1.Compile()).ToList();
```

In the line above, I decided using `dynamic`, but got the exception again. What should I do?

---

I changed my method like this:

```
public static List<TModel> SortForMe<TModel>(this List<TModel> list, string propertyName,SortDirection sortDirection) where TModel:class
    {
        var ins = Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>();
        var prop= ins.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        var propertyType =  prop.PropertyType;

    string exp1 = string.Format("model.{0}", propertyName);
    var p1 = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "model");
    var e1 = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p1 }, null, exp1);

    if (e1 != null)
    {
        if (sortDirection==SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            return list.OrderBy((Func<TModel, propertyType>)e1.Compile()).ToList();
        }

        return list.OrderByDescending((Func<TModel, propertyType>)e1.Compile()).ToList();
    }
        return list;
}
```

I got propertyType using reflection but in Func I couldn't use it like this: `"Func<TModel, propertyType>"` Is there any way to resolve this problem

Thanks for the help.

Comment: haven't got time to go bug hunting, but you should be able to steal most of the lambda code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby - very similar question

Comment: also, `using dynamic = System.Linq.Dynamic;` is really confusing; `dynamic` is contextual keyword; strongly suggest you pick another alias... or just don't use the alias at all

Comment: "using dynamic = System.Linq.Dynamic;" I deleted this. And I changed "var e1 = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p1 }, null, exp1);" Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is indeed boxing, as mentioned in another answer.

```
class S
{
  public int f;
  public S s;
}

{
  Func<S, S> sGetter = s => s.s; // okay
  Func<S, object> objectGetter = s => s.s; // okay
  objectGetter = sGetter; // also okay
}

{
  Func<S, int> intGetter = s => s.f; // okay
  Func<S, object> objectGetter = s => s.f; // still okay
  objectGetter = intGetter; // not okay
}
```

The reason that `Func<S, object> objectGetter = s => s.f` works but the last assignment cannot work is that it actually gets interpreted as `Func<S, object> objectGetter = s => (object)s.f`, and that cast performs a real operation. The `intGetter` and `objectGetter` don't do the same thing, so one cannot be reinterpreted as the other. Realising this, you should be okay if you include that cast yourself. As far as I can tell, DQL (that is what you're using, right?) will do that for you if you simply specify that your desired return type is `object`:

```
var e1 = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p1 }, typeof(object), exp1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has something to do with the boxing of value types, but I cannot be really sure. However, there is a workaround that involves no boxing and both solves your issue and makes your method a bit easier to use.

Instead of string that identifies a property to sort by, you can actually use the lambda expression returning the property. That can be done with following method:

```
private static string GetPropertyName<TObject, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TObject,     TProperty>> property)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

    return propertyInfo.Name;
}
```

Notice that I've wrapped the `Func` delegate into the `Expression` type (you may want to [read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) about it). That way, I can interrogate the expression and find out which members does it use. Of course, this will fail for all but simple `x => x.Property` lambdas, so you may want to do some error checking.

To use it, you will have to change your extension method a little:

```
public static List<TObject> SortForMe<TObject, TProperty>(
    this List<TObject> list, 
    Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> property, 
    SortDirection sortDirection)
{
     string propertyName = GetPropertyName(property);
     ...
     ...          
     // when casting compiled expression to Func, instead of object, use TProperty
     // that way, you will avoid boxing
     var result = list.OrderBy((Func<T, TProperty>)e1.Compile()).ToList();
     ...
     ...
}
```

The actual usage could look like the following:

```
List<Foo> foos = ... ;
foos.SortForMe(x => x.IntegerProperty, SortDirection.Ascending);
foos.SortForMe(x => x.StringProperty, SortDirection.Ascending);
```

The `IntegerProperty` and `StringProperty` are actual properties defined on `Foo` type. There is no need to specify the actual type parameters when using the method - C#'s type inference comes into play here really nicely.

Comment: I can't use lamda in method parameters. Only, I know property name as string.